# How to use class variables in SailsJS?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

In my sailsJS project i use a [Service](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/services) as an API wrapper to communicate with an external API.

For example I want to have a init function and pass parameters like baseUrl, apiKey and after that just call sendRequest(endpoint).

However today i figured out that a service cannot be instantiated but is available globally. Because SailsJS works async it just overrides the variables each time.

So my question in short: What's the right way to use a "class" with class variables, where i can have multiple instances, like i know them from the PHP world?

At first i want to instantiate my API wrapper with a project, that contains basic data such as baseUrl and apiKey.

```
       const ApiService = ServiceBase.getApiService(project);

       ApiService.getEndpoint(endpoint).then(async(response) => {
          // handle response
       }
```

Function get ApiService.
Here i try to set project variables.

```
    getApiService: (project) => {
         this.setConfigParam('apiKey', project.api_key);
         this.setConfigParam('baseUrl', project.url);
        return ShopApiService;
     }
```

Function getEndpoint (Shortcut for GET Requests)

```
    getEndpoint: async function(endpoint) {

       if (ShopApiService.isTokenExpired()) {
          await this.authorizeRequest();
       }

       return this.sendRequest(endpoint);

     }
```

authorizeRequest (Sets accessToken for following requests)

```
    authorizeRequest: async function() {
      let response = await this.postRequest('auth/login', {apiKey: module.exports.config.apiKey});


      if (response && response.statusCode == 200) {
          module.exports.token.updated_at   = Date.now();
          module.exports.config.accessToken = response.body.accessToken;

          return true;
     }

      return false;

  }
```

My problem is that the asynchronous calls override variables like accessToken or baseUrl, so if the request to acquire the access token is finished - it may be for a different request.

Comment: please provide some code of what you want do achieve, maybe then someone could try to help?

Comment: My suggestion... Just try using adonis.js (https://adonisjs.com) instead of sails. You will be able to reuse some bits of php logic you are used to because it was built as a Laravel clone. Sails is not "class friendly" it has its own specific way of doing things

Comment: @LuizCarraro I thought it's a question of basic concepts, but i shared some code so you can better imagine what i am trying to archieve. Thank you.